# Failed to resolve dependencies .?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

Hello i have just imported my android studio project from one pc to another one and when building it is showing the error , Unresolved dependencies detected while building project in offine mode . I have unchecked OFFLINE WORK in Gradle settings . After Unchecking it its now showing the error

```
 A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.0.1/support-v4-23.0.1.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.0.1/support-v4-23.0.1.jar
     file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.0.1/support-v4-23.0.1.pom
     file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.0.1/support-v4-23.0.1.jar
     file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.0.1/support-v4-23.0.1.pom
     file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.0.1/support-v4-23.0.1.jar
 Required by:
     TheFlame:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0
     TheFlame:app:unspecified > com.android.support:design:22.2.0
     TheFlame:app:unspecified > com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0
```

> Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.0.1/support-v4-23.0.1.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.0.1/support-v4-23.0.1.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.0.1/support-v4-23.0.1.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.0.1/support-v4-23.0.1.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.0.1/support-v4-23.0.1.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.0.1/support-v4-23.0.1.jar
>        Required by:
>            TheFlame:app:unspecified > me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.3 > me.dm7.barcodescanner:core:1.8.3

can anyone please help me on this fast.

Comment: please post your build.gradle, maybe you have to download sdk...

Answer (score 4):

[Similiar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769957/couldnt-compile-android-studio-project)

Make sure to update both **"Android Support Repository"** and **"Android Support Library"** in **SDK Manager**

And also ensure the **Gradle Sync** is completed in Android Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) Open SDK Manager

2) Launch standalone SDK Manager

3) Extras and check update for Support Library

4) Install it

5) Sync Gradle

Comment: i have downloaded the latest support library 23.1.1 and its still showing the  same error

Comment: And you have compiled com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 ?? Post build.gradle