# Couldn't compile android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add a materialdrawer library to my project. When I add dependency, my build.gradle looks like this

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.4.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
  }
```

But then i get the following error,

```
>Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.  
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.jar
         file:/C:/Users/abeys/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/abeys/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.jar
         file:/C:/Users/abeys/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/abeys/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.jar
     Required by:
         MyApplication4:app:unspecified
         MyApplication4:app:unspecified > com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.4.8
         MyApplication4:app:unspecified > com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.4.8 > com.mikepenz:materialize:0.2.8
         MyApplication4:app:unspecified > com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.4.8 > com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.2.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.1.1/recyclerview-v7-23.1.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.1.1/recyclerview-v7-23.1.1.jar
         file:/C:/Users/abeys/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.1.1/recyclerview-v7-23.1.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/abeys/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.1.1/recyclerview-v7-23.1.1.jar
         file:/C:/Users/abeys/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.1.1/recyclerview-v7-23.1.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/abeys/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.1.1/recyclerview-v7-23.1.1.jar
     Required by:
         MyApplication4:app:unspecified > com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.4.8
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.1.1/support-annotations-23.1.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.1.1/support-annotations-23.1.1.jar
         file:/C:/Users/abeys/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.1.1/support-annotations-23.1.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/abeys/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.1.1/support-annotations-23.1.1.jar
         file:/C:/Users/abeys/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.1.1/support-annotations-23.1.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/abeys/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.1.1/support-annotations-23.1.1.jar
     Required by:
         MyApplication4:app:unspecified > com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.4.8
```

How to correct this?

Comment: its not the drawer that is not compiling it is the appcompat try removing compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1' if you don't need it

Answer (score 9):

Make sure to update both **"Android Support Repository"** and **"Android Support Library"**.

And also ensure the **Gradle Sync** is completed in Android Studio as @diptia suggested.
[image]

Comment: After installing the necessary packages , it is VERY important to do a gradle Sync and only then build the project . Else , you will continue to see the same error .

Comment: I think `Android Support repository` was renamed to `Local Maven repository for Support libraries`.

Answer (score 1):

> com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.4.8@aar

It seems like the third party library requires the appcompat v23.1.1.

**To solve it :**

1) Make sure that `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1` is installed. Check via your SDK Manager.

2) Add `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'` in your build.gradle file.

3) Remove `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'` from your dependencies.